# How to add multiple songs to a playlist using Spotify API?

Tags: python, json, spotify, spotify-app

I've been having trouble adding multiple songs to my playlist on spotify. Here is what part of my code looks like so far:

```
def add_selected_songs(songs, playlist_id):
        ACCESS_TOKEN = input('Provide Access Token: ')

        request_data = json.dumps(songs)
        URL = f'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{playlist_id}/tracks'
        response = requests.post(
                URL,
                data=request_data,
                headers={
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Authorization": f"Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}"
                })  
        response_json = response.json()
        return response_json
```

The 'songs' variable is an array of song uris I have added from another playlist.
They print out in the following format:

```
['spotify:track:75s1b4uRCk6UPOPBLNdDIA', 'spotify:track:3hqJdqziOPbu422kXaOyII', 'spotify:track:6rdKHwxWa9aqWyoGf1r20v', 'spotify:track:6xQdHOX1Tq3IrKsQdLs0nc', 'spotify:track:66g4mn8jSks0Hu1zEcc81G']
```

I think something might be wrong with the uris or how i did the requests.post() jargon that I still don't understand fully. I don't really know a lot about json, and what little I understand of the spotify api is from youtube videos. I am able to do most things to my playlist like retrieve playlist information like songs and such, and I can add each song individually, but I just can't add multiple songs in one request. If someone could please help me figure out what I am doing wrong that would be much appreciated!

Edit:
Here's what I changed to my code thanks to you guys and your helpful feedback!! Thanks everyone!

```
def add_selected_songs(songs, playlist_id):
ACCESS_TOKEN = input(Provide Access Token: ')

songList = '%2C'.join(songs)
while(songList.find(':') != -1):
    songList = songList.replace(':','%3A')

URL = BASE_URL + f'/playlists/{playlist_id}/tracks?uris={songList}' #forgot to even add the uris earlier too lol
response = requests.post(
        URL,
        headers={
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}"
        })  
response_json = response.json()
return response_json
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and used a generated acces token from the [Add Items to Playlist console](https://developer.spotify.com/console/post-playlist-tracks/), and that worked. So I think you are using an access token that isn't generated with the right scopes.

Comment: Also, can you please include include the response_json in your question?

Comment: Maybe the access token you are/were is expired. Access tokens are valid for online 1 hour.

Answer (score 1):

Spotify Developers page is helpful in a way that will show you how exactly should the request look like: https://developer.spotify.com/console/post-playlist-tracks/

If you try to fill in at least two song ID's, e.g.:

`spotify:track:3hqJdqziOPbu422kXaOyII,spotify:track:3hqJdqziOPbu422kXaOyII`

You will notice the POST request on right side:

`"https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/playlist_id/tracks?uris=spotify%3Atrack%3A3hqJdqziOPbu422kXaOyII%2Cspotify%3Atrack%3A3hqJdqziOPbu422kXaOyII"`

Request does not accept special characters, however ASCII keycodes, so you should join the song IDs by `%2C` and replace the **:** with `%3A`.

Comment: Oh my lord, I know it's been like a week since I posted, but this information was so helpful! I managed to get it to work thanks to this!